# How do I fix java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

The purpose of my code is to have the user enter a car name, then search through the array list and find an object that matches what the user entered. Whenever I run the code, I get the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error. An explanation of what this error means and advice for fixing it is much appreciated :)

```
public static void arrayList()
{
    //Declarations
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();             
    ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
    list.add ("Aston Martin");
    list.add ("Ferrari"); 

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String car = new String();
    String search = new String();


    //Prompts user to enter car name
    System.out.println ("Enter car name: ");    
    car = scan.nextLine();  

    //Searches array list for car
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        search = iterator.next();           
        if (search.equalsIgnoreCase (car))
        {
            System.out.println (search);
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: I feel like a for each loop would have been the tool of choice here instead of an iterator.  PS it would probably also fix your problem

Comment: As a note, it's almost universal convention in Java to put opening braces on the same line as the statement whose block they're opening; this was the official Sun recommendation, and I haven't seen any live code that puts opening braces on their own line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadocs for the relevant collections and [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) are clear:

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

You started an iteration over `list` but then modified it and came back to the iterator.

Don't open your iterator until right before you're about to use it. Even better, since you don't need access to `remove()`, just use an enhanced `for` loop:

```
for(String item: list) {
    if(item.equalsIgnoreCase (car)) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up going with the for loop like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You open an iterator and then change the structure of the list, use a for each loop instead of iterator and if you still want to use ListIterator then open the iterator after adding the elements to the list like this..

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Aston Martin");
    list.add("Ferrari");
    ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, but a little bit different on what involved in `ConcurrentModificationException`. Mine, actually was **a `sort` method call on a collection** while initializing. I had an iteration on data and in another thread a sort method processing. Somehow, the `Collection.sort(...)` process triggers this Exception too.

Initial code on iteration was:

```
 ...
//_Methode_a
    for (final Entry<String, List<GmScope>> scopes : model.getProjectData().entrySet()) {
                    for (final GmScope scope : scopes.getValue()) { //Where exception occures
    ...

//Method_b using a different Thread
...
    Collections.sort(scopeList, new Comparator<GmScope>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(final GmScope o1, final GmScope o2) {
                    return o1.getScopeName().compareTo(o2.getScopeName());
                }

            });
...
```

To fix the problem I have **implement `Comparable` interface to my bean** and define the comparision process there. Then **I have removed the `Collection.sort(...)` defined in my method**.

```
public class GmScope implements Comparable<GmScope> {
...
@Override
        public int compareTo(final GmScope o1) {
            return this.getScopeName().compareTo(o1.getScopeName());
        }
}
```